# Perl search for a value in hash of hash and reassign to another hash

Tags: perl, loops, hash

**I have a sample hash data %dsr_config that dumps as**

```
$VAR1 = 'dc';
$VAR2 = {
          'Alias' => 'DC',
          'Address' => 'street1, street2, '
        };
$VAR3 = 'dsr';
$VAR4 = {
          'daddr' => '192.168.1.1',
          'dscp' => '2',
          'Vip_enabled' => 'True',
          'BL' => '4,8',
          'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
        };
$VAR7 = 'backup';
$VAR8 = {
          'backup' => 'enabled'
        };
```

Now, I am trying to find the hash

```
$VAR3 = 'dsr';
$VAR4 = {
          'daddr' => '192.168.1.1',
          'dscp' => '2',
          'Vip_enabled' => 'True',
          'BL' => '4,8',
          'subnet' => '255.255.255.255'
        };
```

because it has the value 'Vip_enabled' => 'True',

**What I wrote is**

```
    foreach my $key1 (keys %dsr_config) {
            foreach my $key2 (keys $dsr_config{$key1}){
                    if ($key2 =~ /Vip_enabled/){
                            %dsr_config = $dsr_config{$key1};
                            }
                    }
            }

print Dumper %dsr_config;
```

I am trying to over-write the existing %dsr_config with the required data only. But I am getting

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ./test.pl line 43.
Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at ./test.pl line 41.
Line 43 is   %dsr_config = $dsr_config{$key1};
Line 41 is   foreach my $key2 (keys $dsr_config{$key1}){
```

What am I doing wrong here? What do this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop should be:

```
foreach my $key2 (keys %{$dsr_config{$key1}}){
    if ($key2 =~ /Vip_enabled/){
        %dsr_config = ($key1 => $dsr_config{$key1});
    }
}
```

`$dsr_config{$key1}` is a reference to a hash, you have to dereference it if you want to loop on the keys.

Also, I guess you want to exit the outer loop when you've found `Vip_enabled` because the next iteration will produce an undefined result.

```
OUTERLOOP:
foreach my $key1 (keys %dsr_config) {
    foreach my $key2 (keys %{$dsr_config{$key1}}) {
        if ($key2 =~ /Vip_enabled/){
            %dsr_config = ($key1 => $dsr_config{$key1});
            last OUTERLOOP;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you M42. I was trying to understand, what is the difference between using $dsr_config{$key1} and %{$dsr_config{$key1}} in the inner loop? If I do a print Dumper $dsr_config{$key1}, it prints the hash contents of the key dsr.

Comment: This work, if I assign the value to a new hash, say %dsr_config_new. I cannot get %dsr_config to get over-written by the new values. The old values still exist. Do I need to do a **delete** before the **if** statement?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

```
foreach my $key2 (keys $dsr_config{$key1}){
```

should be:

```
foreach my $key2 (keys %{$dsr_config{$key1}}){
```

keys needs a hash.

Similarly...

```
%dsr_config = %{$dsr_config{$key1}};
```

but hard to say for sure with just a fragment.

Comment: Thank you John C. I was trying to understand, what is the difference between using $dsr_config{$key1} and %{$dsr_config{$key1}} in the inner loop? If I do a print Dumper $dsr_config{$key1}, it prints the hash contents of the key dsr.

Comment: To use dumper you have to give it a reference.  So if you have a hash you have to say Dumper(\%hash).  %{ de-references the reference.  A reference is a variable which stores the address of the variable.  (a pointer).